# ScrollMagic is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Intento implementar `ScrollMagic` para la implementación en una nueva pagina web pero me sale el error:

> ScrollMagic is not defined

continuamente. Porque razón sale si tengo todos los scripts implementados en el HTML?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>D.disseny</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="panel blue">
        <b>ONE</b>
    </section>
    <section class="panel turqoise">
        <b>TWO</b>
    </section>
    <section class="panel green">
        <b>THREE</b>
    </section>
    <section class="panel bordeaux">
        <b>FOUR</b>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {
    triggerHook: 'onLeave'
    }
});


var slides = document.querySelectorAll("section.panel");


for (var i=0; i<slides.length; i++) {
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: slides[i]
        })
        .setPin(slides[i])
        .addIndicators() 
        .addTo(controller);
}
```

Comment: Prueba a cargar el js de ScrollMagic después del jquery y, si tu javascript está en script.js, carga este después del js de ScrollMagic. El error se refiere a que intentas acceder a una función que aun no has definido.

Comment: @Carmen Pues ese era el problema! Muchas gracias!